# Google App Script: Send email with attachments from Google Form responses

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am adjusting an existing script that we have for a Google Form that sends a custom email to the desired address, now we want to add a PDF upload in the form and we want to add it to the script in order to be attached in the email.

I will attach my code without the tests I am doing to add the PDF attached from the form so you can see the structure and maybe help me with the import:

```js
function GetContactsAndMakeThemMultiChoise(){
  // Copy your form ID from the browser address bar when you open the form in edit mode
 var form = FormApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXmyformXXXXXXX'); 
var formItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
     var arr=[]
  //i<contacts.length; i++
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
   for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
//Access my contacts and get all contact name that not blank (name.length>0)
    var name = contacts[i].getEmailAddresses();
     if(name.length>0 ){
       arr.push(name); }
    
   }
   
   // Add the contact name to the first dropdown list found in my form
     
     formItems[3].asListItem().setChoiceValues(arr.sort()); 
  }

  // Installation --> copy this code in the inbound code from the form (open form --> three dots --> Scripteditor
// run function createTrigger() once

function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendMail").forForm(FormApp.getActiveForm()).onFormSubmit().create();
}

function getInfo(e) {
  var formResponse;
  if (!e) { formResponse = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses()[FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses().length - 1]; } else { formResponse = e.response; }

  var answers = {};
  formResponse.getItemResponses().forEach(function (r) {
    if (r.getResponse() != undefined && r.getResponse() != "") {
      answers[r.getItem().getTitle()] = r.getResponse();
    }

  });

  var equipo = answers["División"];

  //please enter here your email adresses for the form
  if (equipo == "S1") { sendtheMail("test@test.com", answers) }
  else if (equipo == "R1") { sendtheMail("test@test.com", answers) }
  else {
    { sendtheMail("test@test.com", answers) }
  }


  function sendtheMail(contactName, answers) {

    var tipo = answers["Tipo de"];
    var nombre = answers["Tu nombre"];
    var beneficiario = answers["Nombre"];
    var cantidad = answers["Cantidad"];
    var comentarios = answers["Coments"];
    var propertyid = answers["ID"];
    var paddress = answers["Dirección"];
    
        

    //You can change the mail text under htmlBody
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      name: "Mailing",
      to: "test@test.com",
      subject: "Nueva solicitud " + nombre + " del equipo " + equipo,
      htmlBody: "<p>text " +nombre+ " del equipo " + equipo +
        "<p>El tipo de transferencia es: "+ tipo +
        "<p>El ID: "+ propertyid +
        "<p>La dirección de la propiedad es: "+ paddress +
        "<p>El nombre del beneficiario es: " + beneficiario +
        "<p>Cantidad a transferir: " + cantidad + " €" +
        "<p>Coments: " + comentarios ,
      attachments: ,
      noReply: true
    });
  }
}
```

I modified the names a little bit but everything works as it should. The only thing is just to add the attachment to the email but I cant find the way.

I tried already:

```js
var attach = formResponse.getItemResponses();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(attach[10].getItem());

attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
```

But I am probably not setting it correctly on what we need.

Answer (score 0):

**SUGGESTION:**

Here is a simple implementation sample of attaching a PDF Document from a form response to an email using Google Apps Script.

```
function myFunction() {

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(); 
  var responses = form.getResponses()[1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
  console.log(responses);

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(responses); 

  MailApp.sendEmail('john@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'A file is attached', {
    name: 'Email Script',
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
});
}
```

`form.getResponses()` gets the responses from your Google Form.

`getItemResponses()` gets the item for the response, and then using `getResponse()` gets the response answer itself. In this case, using an attachment from the upload file item, it should return the fileID of the attached PDF from your Google Form.

In this test case, I only have 2 items, and did 2 sample submissions.

[image]

Each response is structured as an object within an array, so getting the second response and the second item is indexed by `1` in my sample as such:

`var responses = form.getResponses()[1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();`

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

References:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponses https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getitemresponses https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getresponse